# Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed

Tags: 2013, publishing, publishingfailed

> Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed.
>       Attempting to deploy a binary 2804 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 2411:

I am getting above error while publishing the page/component from CMS. I know its because we are using same multimedia asset in more than one location in CMS and thats why not able to publish.

My queries.

1) Why this issue usually starts coming after so many days as for many days this issue didn't come and after its start coming continuously, is this not a weired behaviour. because same image we did publish many times from same publication and results were successful.

2) I am trying to solve this by rewrite "PublishBinariesInPackageTemplate" TBB by appending the suffix in image filename eg: file test.png becomes test_8-120.png, but would this solution perfectly works. because we are going to use same image at number of components but then name, TCM will always be same so how this issue will gets resolve as published image name should be unique but here for any publication image name will be same i.e test_8-120.png.

I already gone through all the question on the forum, but didn't find any good solution

Answer (score 2):

This issue is not related to reusing the same MM component in 2 different pages, you only get this problem if you upload two *different* MM components with the same filename, and then try to publish both without adding a suffix to guarantee uniqueness.

To answer 1: You will only start seeing the problem from the point at which you upload and publish a MM component whose file name clashes with an existing published one

To answer 2: You will not get an issue even if the MM comp is reused on 2 pages as it considers it to be the same asset.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is simple, you have two Multimedia Components which have the exact same (binary) filename and one of them has already been deployed (item id: 2011) and the other is currently being published (item id: 2804).

Now you get this error because you are using the Default Template Building Blocks, and they unfortunately don't use unique naming of published binaries, but try to use the original filename, more detail can be found on this old post on Chris Summers' bog http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

That blogpost will also describe you a solution (other than just not uploding images with the same name).

now as for details on your queries:

1. somebody must have updated one of your multimedia component to contain a binary filename similair to one that was already published before. It is typically something which happens after some time, I've heard of customers only experiencing it after 9 months to a year for the first time.
2. As Chris' blogpost mentions, your best option to solve this is indeed creating your own version of `Publish Binaries In Package` TBB, which appends the TCM URI. I'm still hoping that will become an option in the original TBB in a new release of SDL Tridion.