# Facing binary conflict issue with Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, upgrade

We have recently updated our Tridion From 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1 and we are facing the binary conflict issue where at the time of commit step in publishing it says `the binary you are trying to publish already exists`.

Does anyone else face the same issue after upgrade?

Comment: Sounds like you are publishing two multimedia components with the same filename. This is a common thing and fixed in the `Force Unique Binary Filenames` TBB. See http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx . But, you are in an upgrade, I assume the same worked before the upgrade so your error might have a different cause.

Comment: Actually we face the issue when we were publishing a page for the first time in new upgraded environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when editors upload 2 or more multimedia components that have the same filename.  Sometimes this is a legitimate scenario, however, editors often work in silos and upload the exact same asset into the system multiple times, hence adding redundant data to the CM.

For example: Editor John is responsible for creating pages A and B, while Editor Nick is responsible for C and D. Pages A and C have the same image on them therefore they should re-use the same multimedia component; and but John and Nick are working in silos and simply upload the same asset from their Website Assets FTP location into individual MM components. John is the first one to publish his page (page A) and all is good for him. Now Nick tried to publish his page, Page C, which fails with the this Duplicate Binary error.  In this case, `Forcing Unique Binary Filenames` TBB is not the correct answer because it only facilitates redundant data to be created in the CMS.  The correct answer here is to educate the editors so that only one of them owns uploading and naming of the assets into Tridion, while the rest use those assets.

Sometimes this issue occurs when a MM component is published along with a regular component, and after publishing gets deleted from the CM, and then another person uploads a MM component with the original name.  So now the CM is out of sync with the CD and there is no way in the CM to see which items used this deleted component.  In this situation the fix is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14856967/1284894

Answer (score 2):

It means you're trying to save a binary which is already in your website with the same file name.

Check out this link
[Publishing error in Deployment committing phase](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/publishing-error-in-deployment-committing-phase)

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen for every page you try to publish? Or only some pages? Do you have access to the old un-upgraded environment? Does the error happen there for these pages as well?

Duplicate binary file names are a content issue and have nothing to do with the infrastrcture; unless somehow a change to your implementation was made during the upgrade process (or your implementation used non-public APIs) I do not see how a Tridion upgrade can cause this issue. I would therefore be inclined to conclude that the issue and the tridion upgrade are not connected but coincidental...

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below article

http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

I faced the same issue few days back and now it's resolved and working fine. you can also go through the Question which I asked into the forum.

[Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8297/deployment-prepare-commit-phase-failed).